# How to remove file extension from Google App Engine static file URL?

Tags: google-app-engine

I am using Google App Engine standard environment for Java 8, and I would like to serve static HTML files using a URL without the .html extension. I have looked at the similar questions on this site already, but I still cannot find an answer for the standard Java 8 environment.

Comment: Are you aware of [this tutorial](https://alexcican.com/post/how-to-remove-php-html-htm-extensions-with-htaccess/)?

Comment: Would it be a better idea to migrate my application to the Java 11 standard environment, where I can utilize handlers in an app.yaml file?

Comment: This depends from your needs and the complexity of your application. Taking a look at this article to see what is new in [Java 11](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/application-development/turn-it-up-to-eleven-java-11-runtime-comes-to-app-engine) and [Google documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java11/java-differences) may help with your decision.